# "nice meeting you"　Or "nice to meet you"

Tags: expressions, greetings, introductory-words

Here is a situation:
After I meet others for the first time and have a talk, is it correct to say "nice to meet you" or “nice meeting you”？

Comment: Rule of thumb: when first introduced, "Nice to meet you." After you talk for a while, you say goodbye to each other: either "It was nice meeting you" or "It was nice to meet you" is fine.

Comment: Are there any grammar rules behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"nice to meet you" is a set phrase. It is used when you are first introduced to someone:

> Hello, my name is Richard.
> Hello Richard.  Nice to meet you. I'm Jack.

In your context I'd probably use "It was nice meeting you". But either would be fine:

> Well, I'm going home now. See you tomorrow Jill. It was nice meeting you, Jack.
> Goodbye, Richard.

No clear grammar rule, and "It was nice to meet you" would be equally correct.

Comment: Yes, "nice to meet you" is a greeting, "nice meeting you" is a farewell.